# Father son and daughter on camping trip and father dies

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this back in the 80's on HBO I think.

Father, son and daughter I think are canoeing. They stop for the night and set up camp. The young son goes off hunting. The girl and father at camp talk about something about the son/brother. The son is seen following a rabbit then it cuts back to the camp more talking then you hear a gun blast and then seconds later there is another shot. The girl says "See, he missed the first shot" (or something like that). Then the boy comes back carrying two rabbits.

Later the dad dies somehow I don't really remember. So the boy and girl are alone trying to survive. They end up finding a cabin which is owned by a nice guy who takes them in. They can't go to the city which is miles away because winter has come and snowed in. I think after a while the man decides to make the long hike to the city alone to get help for them. They are in the cabin for a long time then a man comes but not the same man this one is really mean. The brother does what he can to protect his sister. After a while the son finds the courage to confront the man and ends up killing him. They end up leaving the cabin to go to the city on the way they find the body of the first guy.

I'm not sure if this is the same movie or two separate movies.

Answer (score 7):

HBO was they key for me. [Cold River](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083741/)
 seemed to be on continuous play in the early 1980s. A man takes his son and daughter into the wilderness. Dad dies, they find a cabin with a helpful man, he leaves and the villain shows up. It gets fuzzy for me here but I believe one of the kids kills the villain.

Comment: @kevin Norris Is this the right answer???